# How to call only the content of the numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of

```
array = [array([ 4.12101269], dtype=float32), array([ 4.44119978], dtype=float32), array([ 4.30688763], dtype=float32), array([ 4.80304432], dtype=float32), array([ 4.47734165], dtype=float32), array([ 4.88290167]]
```

And I want to obtain only

```
array = [4.12101269, 4.44119978, 4.30688763, 4.80304432, 4.47734165, 4.88290167]
```

Is there a way to do that?

I tried

```
array[]
```

Comment: How did you even get this object? It sounds like you should correct whatever code produced this thing, rather than trying to fix things in post-processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a list of arrays, which I can recreate with:

```
In [315]: alist = [array([ 4.12101269], dtype=float32), array([ 4.44119978], dty
     ...: pe=float32), array([ 4.30688763], dtype=float32), array([ 4.80304432],
     ...:  dtype=float32), array([ 4.47734165], dtype=float32), array([ 4.882901
     ...: 67])]
In [316]: alist
Out[316]: 
[array([4.1210127], dtype=float32),
 array([4.4412], dtype=float32),
 array([4.3068876], dtype=float32),
 array([4.8030443], dtype=float32),
 array([4.4773417], dtype=float32),
 array([4.88290167])]
```

`concatenate` or its `hstack` variant does a nice job of joining these arrays into one:

```
In [317]: np.hstack(alist)
Out[317]: 
array([4.12101269, 4.44119978, 4.30688763, 4.80304432, 4.47734165,
       4.88290167])
```

`np.array` can also join them, but adds a dimension:

```
In [318]: np.array(alist)
Out[318]: 
array([[4.12101269],
       [4.44119978],
       [4.30688763],
       [4.80304432],
       [4.47734165],
       [4.88290167]])
```

But it is possible that you have an array of objects, which I can construct as:

```
In [319]: arr = np.empty(len(alist), object)
In [320]: arr[:] = alist
In [321]: arr
Out[321]: 
array([array([4.1210127], dtype=float32), array([4.4412], dtype=float32),
       array([4.3068876], dtype=float32),
       array([4.8030443], dtype=float32),
       array([4.4773417], dtype=float32), array([4.88290167])],
      dtype=object)
```

The `repr` and `str` display is different.  Note the missing commas below:

```
In [322]: print(arr)
[array([4.1210127], dtype=float32) array([4.4412], dtype=float32)
 array([4.3068876], dtype=float32) array([4.8030443], dtype=float32)
 array([4.4773417], dtype=float32) array([4.88290167])]
```

But `hstack` still works:

```
In [323]: np.hstack(arr)
Out[323]: 
array([4.12101269, 4.44119978, 4.30688763, 4.80304432, 4.47734165,
       4.88290167])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a list of `numpy` arrays. In this case, you can convert to `numpy` array, and call `flatten`:

```
myarray = [np.array([ 4.12101269], dtype=float), np.array([ 4.44119978], dtype=float), np.array([ 4.30688763], dtype=float), np.array([ 4.80304432], dtype=float), np.array([ 4.47734165], dtype=float), np.array([ 4.88290167])]

np.array(myarray).flatten()

# array([ 4.12101269,  4.44119978,  4.30688763,  4.80304432,  4.47734165, 4.88290167])
```